# PL/Sql Issue when compiling

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, toad

Apparently I need a second set of eyes because for the life of me I cannot see what the problem is.  I created a "test" package to test my package code and I keep getting the error "Invalid SQL" or "subprogram or cursor" contained in package doesn't exist.  It's driving me mad ... here's my code, simple stuff really ... the package declaration complies fine, the package body gives me the error.  Whatever function I put at the top of the package body will compile, the other 2 will not and gives me one of the 2 errors described above.  I originally had this in another package that contains over 10,000 lines of code, but I created this test package because I was getting all kinds of weird error messages when I compiled it, so I took it out and that package compiles and runs fine.  I'm using Toad v10.0.0.41 to access the database, not Sql*Plus, been using Toad for many years.

Package:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE SomeSchema.TestPackage AS

FUNCTION PrimaryContactFullName (pPrimaryContact IN Varchar2, pFatherName IN Varchar2, pMothername IN Varchar2) RETURN VARCHAR2;

FUNCTION PrimaryContactFirstName(pPrimaryContact IN Varchar2, pFatherFirstName IN Varchar2, pMotherFirstname IN Varchar2) RETURN VARCHAR2;

FUNCTION PrimaryContactLastName(pPrimaryContact IN Varchar2, pFatherLastName IN Varchar2, pMotherLastname IN Varchar2) RETURN VARCHAR2;

END TestPackage;
/
```

Package Body:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY SomeSchema.TestPackage IS
    FUNCTION PrimaryContactFirstName(pPrimaryContact IN Varchar2, pFatherFirstName IN Varchar2, pMotherFirstName IN Varchar2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
        W_FullName Varchar2(100);
    BEGIN
            IF Upper(pPrimaryContact) = 'MOTHER' Then
                W_FullName :=  pMotherFirstName;
            ELSIF Upper(pPrimaryContact) = 'FATHER' Then
                W_FullName :=  pFatherFirstName;
            ELSE
                W_FullName :=  pMotherFirstName;
            END IF;
            RETURN W_FullName;
        END;
    END;
    FUNCTION PrimaryContactLastName(pPrimaryContact IN Varchar2, pFatherLastName IN Varchar2, pMotherLastname IN Varchar2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
            W_FullName Varchar2(100);
    BEGIN
            IF Upper(pPrimaryContact) = 'MOTHER' Then
                W_FullName :=  pMotherLastName;
            ELSIF Upper(pPrimaryContact) = 'FATHER' Then
                W_FullName :=  pFatherLastName;
            ELSE
                W_FullName :=  pMotherLastName;
            END IF;
            RETURN W_FullName;
   END;
    FUNCTION PrimaryContactFullName(pPrimaryContact IN Varchar2, pFatherName IN Varchar2, pMothername IN Varchar2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
       W_FullName Varchar2(100);
    BEGIN
            IF Upper(pPrimaryContact) = 'MOTHER' Then
                W_FullName :=  pMotherName;
            ELSIF Upper(pPrimaryContact) = 'FATHER' Then
                W_FullName :=  pFatherName;
            ELSE
                W_FullName :=  pMotherName;
           END IF;
            RETURN W_FullName;
        END;
    END;
/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra `END;` statement between then end of your `PrimaryContactFirstName` function and the start of your `PrimaryContactLastName` function.

Comment: Not only is there an extra end in the beginning, there's an extra end in the middle AND .... no end .... wait for it ..... at the end!  Lol ... wow ... I just couldn't see it ...

Comment: This is where formatting your code is helpful. This kind of error jumps out at you.

Comment: I always format my code just for that reason, just couldn't "see" this one.  Now that I can, it's so damn obvious ... lol ....

Comment: The code posted above only had one extra END; statement.  I removed that and it compiled just fine in my test db.